# Sass::SyntaxError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 4) for `rgba'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, appharbor

I change the css of my app and when I have wanted to heroku pushed his message returned the following error:

here is the css:`

```
.subHeading{
display:block;
font:2.357em/1.151em 'PT Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /*33px/38px*/
margin:0 0 1em;
text-align:center;
color:#7a7a7a;
text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.grey{
background:#7e8794;
color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #f6f6f6;
border-top:1px solid #f6f6f6;

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 6px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75),
          inset 0 -6px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 6px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75),
          inset 0 -6px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow:         inset 0 6px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75),
          inset 0 -6px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.grey h1{
color:#fff;
text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.grey h2{
text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.grey .subHeading{
color:#d9e7fb;
text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

* +html .btn{margin:0;}
.btn span{
color:#fff;
padding:0 1.25em;
display:block;
text-shadow: 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0px 3px 
rgba(255,255,255,255,.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
box-shadow:         inset 0 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);

-webkit-border-radius: 1.25em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.25em;
border-radius: 1.25em;
}
.btnSmall{
padding:0.278em;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:1.214em;
line-height:2.35em;
background:#798493;
font-weight:bold;
border:1px solid #505a68;

-webkit-border-radius: 1.47em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.47em;
border-radius: 1.47em;

-webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
transition: background 0.5s ease; 

-moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.36);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.36);
box-shadow:         0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.36);
}
.btnSmall span{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0 1.47em;
display:block;
text-shadow: 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

border:1px solid #566270;
background:#606a78;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(98,119,149) 0%, rgb(160,188,226) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(98,119,149) 0%, rgb(160,188,226) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(98,119,149) 0%, rgb(160,188,226) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(98,119,149) 0%, rgb(160,188,226) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(98,119,149) 0%, rgb(160,188,226) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(98,119,149)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(160,188,226))
);

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 2px 2px -2px 
          rgba(255,255,255,255,.75),
          inset 0 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.75),
          inset 0 0 0 #fff;
box-shadow:         inset 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.75),
          inset 0 0 0 #fff;

-webkit-border-radius: 1.25em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.25em;
border-radius: 1.25em;
}
.btn:hover {
background:#1b4648;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.btnSmall:hover span{
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(109,131,164) 0%, rgb(169,199,241) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(109,131,164) 0%, rgb(169,199,241) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(109,131,164) 0%, rgb(169,199,241) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(109,131,164) 0%, rgb(169,199,241) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(109,131,164) 0%, rgb(169,199,241) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(109,131,164)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(169,199,241))
);
}

.btnGreen span{
border:1px solid #5e9048;
background:#75cf44;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(80,153,46) 0%, rgb(117,207,68) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(80,153,46) 0%, rgb(117,207,68) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(80,153,46) 0%, rgb(117,207,68) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(80,153,46) 0%, rgb(117,207,68) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(80,153,46) 0%, rgb(117,207,68) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(80,153,46)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(117,207,68))
);
}
.btnBlue span{
background:#52b3d3;
border:1px solid #67a2b4;
color:#fff;

background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(66,153,179) 0%, rgb(82,179,211) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(66,153,179) 0%, rgb(82,179,211) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(66,153,179) 0%, rgb(82,179,211) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(66,153,179) 0%, rgb(82,179,211) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(66,153,179) 0%, rgb(82,179,211) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(66,153,179)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(82,179,211))
);
}
.formRow{
width:100%;
margin:0 0 1.5em;
}
.formRow:after{
content:"";
display:block;
clear:both;
}
.textField{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid #505a68;
background:#798493;
font-weight:bold;
padding:0.5em;

-webkit-border-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius: 2em;
border-radius: 2em;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box; 

-moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.36);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.36);
box-shadow:         0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.36);
}
input,
textarea{
display:block;
background:#fff;
font:1em/1.214em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  /*14px/17px*/
color:#444;
width:100%;
padding:0.75em 1.5em;
border:1px solid #505762;
margin:0;

resize:none;

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow:         inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

-webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
border-radius: 1.5em;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
textarea {
overflow:auto;
height:10.812em;
}
* +html input,
* +html textarea,
* +html .textField{
width:99%;
padding:0;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:    #444; 
}
:-moz-placeholder {
color:    #444;
}
.columns{width:100% }
.columns:after{
content:"";
display:block;
clear:both;
}
.columns > div,
.columns > article{
float:left;
vertical-align:top;
}
.columns h2{text-align:left;}
.half{
width:48.0%;
margin:1.3%;
}
.oneThird{
width:32%;
margin:1%;
}
.columns > div:first-child,
.columns > article:first-child{margin-left:0;}
.oneThird +.oneThird +.oneThird,
.threeForth + .oneForth,
.oneForth + .half,
.half + .half,
.half + .oneForth + .oneForth,
.last{
float:right;
margin-right:0;
}
.oneForth{width:25%;}
.threeForth{width:74.5%;}
.buttons{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
margin:2.5em 0 0
}
.buttons > span{
background:url(../img/sep-vert.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
display:inline-block;
font-size:1.714em;
line-height:1.125em;
padding:1em 0.75em;
margin:0 -1px 0 -2px;
}
* +html .buttons > span{margin:0 20px;}
.buttons > span em{
font-style:normal;
display:block;
background:#eaeaea;
}
.imgHolder{
display:inline-block;
padding:1px;
background:#fff;
border:6px solid #cecece;
margin-bottom:1em;
max-width:100%;
overflow:hidden;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
* +html .imgHolder{
max-width:93.5%;
border-width:3%;
padding:0;
}
.imgHolder img{display:block;}
.grey .imgHolder{
border-color:#646e7d;
}
/*main styles*/
#pagewidth {width:100%;}
#header{
position: fixed;
z-index:100;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height:49px;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
padding:1.143em 0;
background:#404751;

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 0 #fff,
          inset 0 -20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #fff,
          inset 0 -20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 0 #fff,
          inset 0 -20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
#content{padding:82px 0 0;}
#mainNav{text-align:center;}
#mainNav li{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 7px;
}
#mainNav a{
color:#fff;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
padding:0.278em;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:1.214em;
line-height:2.35em;
background:#2d3239;
font-weight:bold;

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow:         inset 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

-webkit-border-radius: 1.47em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.47em;
border-radius: 1.47em;
}
#mainNav a span{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0 1.25em;
display:block;
text-shadow: 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.31), 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

border:1px solid #202329;
background:#606a78;

background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(65,72,82) 0%, rgb(96,106,120) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(65,72,82) 0%, rgb(96,106,120) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(65,72,82) 0%, rgb(96,106,120) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(65,72,82) 0%, rgb(96,106,120) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(65,72,82) 0%, rgb(96,106,120) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(65,72,82)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(96,106,120))
);

-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 2px 2px -2px 
          rgba(255,255,255,255,.75),
          inset 0 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.75),
          inset 0 0 0 #fff;
box-shadow:         inset 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.75),
          inset 0 0 0 #fff;

-webkit-border-radius: 1.25em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.25em;
border-radius: 1.25em;
}
#mainNav a:active{
top:1px;
}
#mainNav a:hover span ,
#mainNav li.active span {
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(71,83,101) 0%, rgb(123,145,177) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(71,83,101)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(123,145,177))
)
}
.gallery{
background:url(../img/sep-hor.gif) no-repeat 50% 0;
padding:2px 0;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:81.25%;
position:relative;
}
.gallery:after{
content:"";
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:url(../img/sep-hor.gif) no-repeat 50% 0;
width:100%;
height:2px;
}
.news > div{
border:1px solid #505a68;
position:relative;
padding:0 0 50px;
margin:0 0 30px;
height:1%;
}
.news > div:after{
content:"";
display:block;
clear:both;
}
.news h3{
font-size:1.714em;
line-height:2.583em;
text-align:center;
margin:0 0 0.83em;
border-top:1px solid #909eb2;
border-bottom:1px solid #545b65;
background:#5d6a7c;

background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(93,106,124) 0%, rgb(126,137,153) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(93,106,124) 0%, rgb(126,137,153) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(93,106,124) 0%, rgb(126,137,153) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(93,106,124) 0%, rgb(126,137,153) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(93,106,124) 0%, rgb(126,137,153) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(93,106,124)),
  color-stop(1, rgb(126,137,153))
);
}
.news h3 a{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.news .content{
width:83%;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
}
.news .readMore{
position:absolute;
top:100%;
margin:-2.143em 0 0;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
} 
.slides{
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}
.slides li{
padding:0;
display: none;
position:relative;
background:url(../img/sep-vert.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
* +html .slides li{
display:inline;
zoom:1;
margin:0;
}
.slides blockquote{
float:right;
width:48%;
margin:2.5em 0 0;
}
.slides blockquote:first-child{float:left;}
#map{
border:1px solid #535d6b;
padding:0.428em;
background:#798493;
margin:0 0 1em;
}
#map .imgHolder{
height:1%;
overflow:hidden;
background:#fff;
padding:1px;
border:0;
margin:0;
display:block;
}
#map .imgHolder img{
width:100%;
}
.form{width:92%;}
#testimonials{
margin-top:-2.857em;
}
#testimonials .row{
padding:0;
background:url(../img/sep-hor.gif) no-repeat 50% 1.5em;
}
#testimonials .row:first-child{
background:none;
}
#testimonials{background:none;}
#testimonials:after{display:none;}
#footer{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
padding:24px 0;
color:#fff;
line-height:16px;
}
#footer a{
color:#fff;
}
#footer .copy{float:right;}
#message p{margin: 0;}
.error_message{
padding: 5px 10px!important;
border-width: 2px !important;
background:rgba(247,0,0,0.5) !important;
margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.ok_message{
padding: 10px 15px!important;
background:rgba(57,143,20,0.5) !important;
margin: 0 0 15px;
}
}
```

Here is my reference that the terminal:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   I, [2014-09-22T13:27:18.698645 #606]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/public/assets/application-4d89252671a18b5c14713d875d619d90.js
   rake aborted!
```

it's this line that I do not understand:

```
   Sass::SyntaxError: Alpha channel 255.75 must be between 0 and 1 for `rgba'
   (in /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
   (sass):391
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:162:in `rescue in _perform'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:99:in `_perform'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/list.rb:71:in `block in _perform'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/list.rb:71:in `map'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/list.rb:71:in `_perform'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:298:in `visit_prop'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:320:in `visit_rule'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:362:in `visit_media'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128:in `visit_root'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_0e049181-beb7-4525-b60f-4ff175a73837/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:metrobox.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:metrobox.git'
```

Can you help me please?!

Comment: Please don't just dump your whole overly large scss file into the question. Instead, please distill the shortest complete example demonstrating the erroneous behaviour and put that into your question. That way, your question will be much more helpful and so much easier to understand as we don't need to hunt for the interesting location. Please refer to the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You have a syntax in your code and I don't understand why you expect anyone on StackOverflow to fix it for you. Took me 30 seconds to find this `-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 2px 2px -2px 
          rgba(255,255,255,255,.75),` which is probably less than it took you to post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
.btnSmall span{
#....
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 2px 2px -2px 
      rgba(255,255,255,255,.75),
      inset 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

There is one of `255` too much. There are 3 occurrences of this in your code. Simply search for `rgba(255,255,255,255,.75)` to find them all.

Comment: Thanks but, I have removed a 255 but its always return me the same error.

Comment: it gives me this: Sass::SyntaxError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4) for `rgba'